# How To Use Diff Row-wise

Tags: r

I have a column with values `c(80,70,50,40, 30)`. I need to subtract(`80-70`) and so on as show below.

Below is the column and desired output. First value required is `0` and then after diff value. I'm trying this in R.

```
Col 1   Diff
80      0
70     10
50     20
40     10
30     10
```

Answer (score 3):

You want `diff`:

```
c(0, -diff(c(80, 70, 50, 40, 30)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c(80,70,50,40,30)
y <- c(100, 120, 30, 20, 10)

df <- data.frame(x, y)

df$x1 <- c(0, abs(diff(x)))
df$y1 <- c(0, abs(diff(y)))
```

However, the above only works when the values are in descending order...so use this one instead.

```
df$x2 <- c(0, 0-(diff(x))) 
df$y2 <- c(0, 0-(diff(y)))
```

Comment: yes i guess if the columns are not always in decreasing order that would be the case